# Why is Bind The Monster useful?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have [Bind the Monster](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBind%20the%20Monster%5d). I really don't see a use for it. Is it useful, and how?

It's an Aura Enchantment for {U} with

> Enchant creature
>
> When Bind the Monster enters the battlefield, tap enchanted creature. It deals damage to you equal to its power.
>
> Enchanted creature doesn't untap during its controller's untap step.

Comment: soft removal in blue for 1! at common! sounds like a pretty solid card in limited formats

Answer (score 15):

Bind the Monster is the newest card [from a decent list](https://scryfall.com/search?q=oracle%3A%22Enchanted%20creature%20doesn%27t%20untap%22%20oracle%3A%22tap%20enchanted%20creature%22&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name) that both taps the creature when you play it, and keeps it tapped. Most of these that do only that cost 3 or 4 mana, the ones that cost only 1 have significant downsides to them:

- [Tangle Kelp](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTangle%20Kelp%5d) only works at most every other turn - since it keeps it tapped only if it attacked last turn.
- [Paralyze](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bParalyze%5d) lets them pay mana to untap it, they can decide if it's worth 4 mana to have their big threat back for the turn.
- [Bubble Snare](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBubble%20Snare%5d) doesn't tap unless you kick it, making it a 4 cost.

And then we have the new 1 cost, Bind the Monster, which also has the creature do damage to you when you use it. It does that damage only once however, then it can't attack, it is also not combat damage - so effects like [Fynn, the Fangbearer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFynn%2c%20the%20Fangbearer%5d) giving poison counters, or [Master of Cruelties](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMaster%20of%20Cruelties%5d) setting your life to 1 point won't happen. The creature being kept tapped means it won't be able to attack or block, or use any effects that require it to tap, so no more using [Elvish Archdruid](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElvish%20Archdruid%5d) to generate a ton of mana in an elf deck.

Most of the time it's easy enough to remove a creature instead. Most kill spells cost 2 or 3 mana like [Poison the Cup](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPoison%20the%20Cup%5d), most spells that exile cost 3 or 4 - neither of these are things that blue tends to do, kill spells tend to be black, exile spells tend to be white. Blue usually deals with creatures three ways:

1. Countering them before they resolve - this is very time specific, you need to do this when the creature is cast, but it's usually the most efficient and permanent solution.
2. [Unsummon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=136218)ing them. This sends the creature back to the hand, so it's only a temporary fix, your opponent can usually just play it again next turn, but this tends to be the cheapest option at 1 or 2 mana.
3. Tapping the creature and keeping it tapped. This is the middle ground. The creature is still on the battlefield, but it can't do much while there. It usually costs about the same as more permanent removal in black or white.

There's a few bad habits and ways of thinking that tend to take players a while to get out of, I suffered from these myself when I started:

- Avoid losing life - life is a resource just like mana, and it's only the last point that matters. Winning with 20 or more life counts just as much as winning with only one point left.
- Play the strongest cards - It's really a balance between how much it costs and how much it does. Low cost spells that have good, if not spectacular effects can often be better in the long run, you can play them easier when you need them.
- Auras on my own creatures - Auras can go on whatever they say they can go on, when it says "Enchant Creature" that means it can enchant any creature you can target - not just yours. Most of the creature auras in Magic are meant to give a boost to creatures, but there are still a good number meant to weaken or hinder a creature, those ones you want to put on your opponent's creatures.

Answer (score 12):

One point you might have missed is that Bind the Monster can target any creature in play. So at least one use for it is to enchant an opponent's creature, which forces it to become tapped and get stuck like that, meaning that:

1. It can't attack you.
2. It can't be assigned as a blocker against your attacking creatures.
3. It can't use any activated abilities that involve tapping it for its cost.

All three of these are *very* good reasons to want an opponent's creature to be tapped.

There may also be occasions where you want one of your own creatures tapped or where you want to take damage for some reason, but those will be very combo-specific.

Comment: Something that's probably worth addressing is the fact that Bind the Monster deals damage to you, the caster, thanks to that sentence at the end of the second ability. A player might see it and think "wait, so either it attacks me and I take damage, or I use this to stop it attacking... and I still take damage. What's the big idea!?"

Comment: @doppelgreener this is incorrect - the damage is dealt by the creature, not the aura - this is clear in the rulings on gatherer ("The enters-the-battlefield ability triggers even if the enchanted creature is already tapped. That creature will still deal damage to you.") and in how the card is written (self references use the card name, references to 'it' are used for the targets of the spell or ability)

Comment: @Andrew I know that. The source of damage here is nitpicking, what's important here is the aura results in you taking damage as though the creature had hit you anyway and that factors into evaluation of the card's usefulness. I am suggesting the answer may want to comment on that.

Comment: @doppelgreener It can definitely matter, [depending on what you are binding](https://scryfall.com/search?q=oracle%3A%22deals+damage+to+a+player%22&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name)

Comment: @Andrew I am directing you to the fact that nitpicking on the source of damage is _not important to me providing this feedback,_ and this correcting me is beside the point of it.

Comment: To be completely explicit, the key point is that binding a creature causes you to take damage only *once* (when you cast it), instead of the likelihood of taking damage turn after turn as the creature continues to attack. It's a low-cost way for blue to neutralize a threat. No, it doesn't completely nerf every possible creature, and yes, it has drawbacks (the damage, for one), but its a tool in the blue player's arsenal.

Answer (score 5):

What you have there is an aura that can make a lot of creatures almost useless.

Whatever creature you enchant it to will become tapped, and won't untap like normal at the start of its controllers turn. So it basically stays untapped, unless some other card untaps it. A tapped creature cannot attack. It cannot block. It cannot activate abilities with the tap symbol.

The fact that you're dealt some damage is balanced by it only costing a single mana (compare to e.g. [Claustrophobia](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bClaustrophobia%5d)). That does mean you'd be more inclined to use it on a small creature with an important tap ability or a low-powered blocker than on a large creature that wants to attack you.

The creature isn't gone, so there are ways to get use out of a Bound monster. For instance, abilities that don't have tapping as cost are still present and can be used, the Binding can be destroyed bringing the creature back into full use, or the creature could be sacrificed if its controller is asked to sacrifice a creature. Also, if the creature's controller can find any other way of untapping it, then it can be used entirely as normal until it is tapped again.

Comment: It certainly doesn't "make a creature basically useless", because there are a lot of cards that cannot be answered by Bind the Monster (or is only partially answered). Many of these are top threats too, such as Walking Ballista, Noble Heirarch, Dark Confidant ... I would amend the first sentence.

Comment: @Allure I said "can make", not "makes". Also, I did list a number of ways that a creature may still be used. But sure, I can make it clearer.

Comment: @Allure Your nitpick is silly: Bind the Monster shuts down the two main threats from the vast, vast majority of creatures: conventional attacks and tapping activated abilities. Of course there are always exceptions in magic, but I'd say "making most creatures basically useless" is a decent summary for a beginning player.

Comment: @BradC I didn't do the statistics, but I will point out that at competitive level, many creatures are not completely shut down by Bind the Monster, and in fact it is almost a defining characteristic - "does this creature do something if it's immediately removed" is a common question, and if the answer is no, then it had better be a game-winning bomb. Look at all the most played creatures in Modern and tell me which are actually answered well Bind the Monster: https://www.mtggoldfish.com/format-staples/modern/full/creatures

Comment: @Allure When answering the question "This aura seems entirely useless, how can someone possibly have a use for this?", I don't think the framing of the question is with regards to current standard or modern meta. That is just a hunch, though. That being said, the very first entry on that list is beautifully answered by the Binding, as it's an offensive attacker that likely has only a single power when you Bind it, and Stoneforge Mystic can't put equipments into play.

Comment: @BradC In the top 10 the only cards affected are Auriok Champion & Kor Firewalker, neither of which one is likely to play against in a blue deck. In 11-20, Soul-Scar Mage, Birds of Paradise & Giver of Runes are shut down but are is also 1-mana. Tarmogoyf, Death's Shadow & Wurmcoil Engine are shut down, but are all usually big enough that the life loss is relevant. Furthermore I doubt you actually want to play Bind the Monster against decks playing Wurmcoil.

Comment: @BradC in fact, I have a hard time finding a *single* creature in the top 50 most played creatures that is cleanly answered by Bind the Monster. Just saying.

Comment: @Arthur Monastery Swiftspear has Haste, which means that even if it is answered immediately by Bind the Monster, it has already dealt damage, and so traded advantageously.

Comment: @Allure Maybe. But again, I think you're overthinking this, applying way too much cutting-edge theory. The point isn't "Why would a top 8 modern deck ever use this?", but rather "Why is this even printed?"

Comment: @Arthur yes, context definitely matters. I don't doubt for example that Bind the Monster is a good pickup in limited. But it's because context matters that "it's makes a lot of creatures basically useless" is too strong of a generalization.

Comment: @Allure The context is a person who can't see the point of that aura, and what kind of things they might face, or even imagine facing. I think I'm fine. You're free to disagree, of course. But I don't think you'll convince me.

Comment: In fact this is an extremely playable card in Kaldheim draft or sealed, as it is one of only a couple of creature "removal/shutdown" cards in blue (all the appropriate caveats that it doesn't work for 100% of effects on 100% of creatures, even in Kaldheim). But yeah, this is not a "Pro Tour Constructed" deck tech question, this is a "why would I ever play this" question, presumably because the poster didn't understand we are intended to play this on our opponent's creatures, not our own.

Comment: @Allure That top ten list must have changed in the past two weeks, since Firewalker is now 11. Of the list right now Monastery Swiftspear and Goyf are shut down completely, but many of the others are still very hindered by it, Stoneforge Mystic and Noble Heirarch still have some of their use, but they also had tap effects you lose. At least half of the cards in that top ten are completely shut down or lose half their use when bound.

Comment: @Andrew Swiftspear has haste, Stoneforge Mystic has an ETB effect, and Noble Heirarch still has Exalted. Bind trades disadvantageously against every one of the creatures you mention except Goyf, but even then, Goyf is usually quite big (i.e. the damage taken is substantial) and it is not an expensive card, so it's not a blowout (as compared to, say, hitting a Baneslayer Angel with a 1-mana removal spell). Compare the premier removal spells of Modern - Path to Exile, Fatal Push, and Lightning Bolt.

Comment: @Allure Swiftspear would get one hit in then, probably relatively low powered, and then likely one point of damage when it binds, Hierarch has exalted but it wouldn't be used if it weren't also a good mana source and binds for 0 life none of the other 1 drop exalted see play, Batterskull is the only equipment in the top 50 cards according to the list you sent, it now costs 3 extra because you can't stoneforge it in, heavily throwing off tempo -   Binding still extremely limits each of these cards - good solutions don't need to be perfect solutions.

Comment: @Andrew Swiftspear is only played in aggro decks (Burn, Death's Shadow) and taking damage matters. Note also if you Bind Swiftspear on turn 1 then there's a good chance you have to fetch for a basic or risk having to shock yourself with a shockland, which can be dangerous, especially since you do not gain tempo from the play (you are trading 1 mana for 1 mana). Noble Heirarch's Exalted matters, that's a big part of the reason why it sees more play than Birds of Paradise. Finally, not being able to Mystic Batterskull is obviously not ideal, but opponent has still drawn a card ... (cont)

Comment: Magic is also not just modern, as much as some people seem to act like it is. Standard is still a thing, as is limited, particularly with most of magic being on MTGA right now with the pandemic, along with other formats only really played in MTGA events that are even more restricted, like standard artisan. Not being a staple in a format with as big a card pool as modern (or worse, EDH, vintage and legacy) doesn't mean a card is bad by any means.

Comment: @Andrew that extra card can be utilized in a few ways, e.g. you now have a card to discard to Liliana of the Veil's +1, or it can be converted into a real card with Jace the Mind Sculptor's 0 ability. Finally, note that you see Batterskull in that list only because (almost) every Mystic deck runs it. Decks with Mystic will usually have a Sword of X and Y (e.g. Sword of Feast and Famine) as well, and those don't show up since there are several of those. The Swords are much more castable without Mystic.

Comment: @Andrew you can say the same of Standard actually. Look at the list of top Standard creatures (https://www.mtggoldfish.com/format-staples/standard/full/creatures) and tell me, how many of them are actually answered effectively by Bind the Monster? Bind is not a good card in constructed. It's a good card in limited, but not constructed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121203/discussion-between-andrew-and-allure).

Comment: @Allure The question was never "Is Bind a good card?" It is "How in the blazes would anyone ever find a use for it?" Even in constructed, it is useful. It is not strong enough to be competitive, but that's entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @Arthur as I pointed out in the chat with Andrew, Bind is not seeing play even in the lowest-powered constructed format. If you call it useful even then, virtually every card is useful. Like, before the Companion nerf, Kaheera the Orphanguard saw play in full creatureless control decks because having an eighth card in starting hand (even if it is just a vanilla 3/2 vigilance) is just *that* good. Bind is a limited-only card. I have no experience with Kaldheim limited since I mostly quit Magic, but looking at drafting resources, it's not good even there. Playable, but not good.

Comment: I'm not claiming Bind is useless - it can certainly have uses in limited (it is playable after all). I only objected when you wrote it makes a creature basically useless, which it doesn't, because there are a great number of creatures which trade advantageously vs. Bind.

Comment: @Allure Let me amend "useful" to "could be of use". Or whatever. As i said, I'm not claiming is competitive. You know that. I don't know what else to say. I've tried very hard to specify this, yet you fight me. Why?

Comment: Because your original answer said it "makes a creature basically useless" and that is not true. The edited answer is better, but I still didn't upvote, because there are still a lot of creatures which Bind does not answer. I don't know what else to say, either.

Answer (score 3):

**Bind the Monster is useful because it can shut down(*) an opponent's creature.**

First, note that while some auras (like [Setessan Training](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSetessan%20Training%5d)) can *only* enchant creatures you control, auras that simply say "enchant creature" can be played on creatures controlled by any player. Clearly some (like [Arcane Flight](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArcane%20Flight%5d)) make more sense to play on your own creatures, and others (like [Withercrown](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWithercrown%5d)) make more sense to play on your opponent's.

When you play [Bind the Monster](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBind%20the%20Monster%5d) on an opponent's creature, you take a single shot of damage, but then that creature gets (and stays) tapped as long as the aura is on it. Tapped creatures can't attack or block, and can't play any activated abilities that require tapping (like the abilities on [Axgard Cavalry](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAxgard%20Cavalry%5d) or [Frost Augur](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFrost%20Augur%5d)).

So for the cost of 1 blue mana (and the downside of taking some damage) you've effectively neutralized(*) one of your opponent's creatures.

(*) Caveats:

1. Can it shut down all possible abilities on all possible creatures? No, many creatures have other abilities besides attacking (or tapping). If you play this on [Toski, Bearer of Secrets](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bToski%2c%20Bearer%20of%20Secrets%5d), *it* won't be able to attack, but Toski's ability still lets your opponent draw cards when *other* creatures deal combat damage to you. If you play this on [Koma, Cosmos Serpent](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKoma%2c%20Cosmos%20Serpent%5d), then Koma can't attack, but you're still likely to lose to all the 3/3 serpent tokens Koma keeps making.
2. Will the damage hurt? Of course! But so does taking attack damage! So only play this on creatures you can't block or handle in other ways.
3. Are there better ways to destroy/remove/neutralize creatures? Probably! Depends on what format you're playing, and what other cards (and colors) you have available. But if you're playing blue in a Kaldheim-only draft or sealed deck, then this is a very playable card!
4. Can your opponent remove the enchantment? Maybe they can, but hopefully they missed a turn of attacks. Or perhaps you just needed to sideline that one pesky blocker so you could attack for the win!
5. Other caveats apply: *Only useful when playing blue. Not useful against decks without creatures. You can't play this card on creatures with hexproof or protection from blue. This card is better in limited (draft and sealed) than in constructed play. There are other ways to untap tapped creatures. Playing this card on creatures with built-in untap abilities like [Battered Golem](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBattered%20Golem%5d) won't do anything useful. Definitely don't play this on your own [Serra Avatar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSerra%20Avatar%5d) or [Soul of Eternity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSoul%20of%20Eternity%5d).*